# Curing sick people and maximizing social impact

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I have the hardest time modeling situations (find variables and the right constraints), so I am looking for hints on what I'm missing instead of the actual answer.

## Here is the problem and my work on it:

Suppose we have two types of disease : **Type A** and **Type B**.

We have 2 types of resources to cure these, **Resource** 1 and **Resource 2**.

To cure the sick people we need:

- For type A : 9 resources 1 + 6 resources 2
- For type B : 14 resources 1 + 5 resources 2

### Other info

- We have 630 resources 1 and 300 resources 2.
- There are 40 sick people on the waiting list for every type
- We want to maximize the social impact. The social impact is calculated as follows: 1000 for every type A cured and 1200 for every type B cured.

### What I've done so far :

1) Actions :

- Attribute Resource 1 to Type A (X11)
- Attribute Resource 1 to Type B (X12)
- Attribute Resource B to Type A (X21)
- Attribute Resource B to Type B (X22)

2) Objective
$$ 1000( \frac {\frac {x11}{9}+\frac {x21}{6}}{2})+1200(\frac {\frac {x21}{14}+\frac {x22}{5}}{2}) $$

*Note : I know this objective isn't right but this is all I could find. I don't know how to remove the results if the number of resources given is lower to the amount needed.*

*For example, if 8 resources 1 and 5 resources 2 are given to type A, I get social impact when I shouldn't because no one has been cured.*

3) Constraints

Resources:
$$x11+x12 \leqslant 630$$
$$x21+x22 \leqslant 300$$

Patients :
$$\frac {x11}{9} \leqslant 40$$
$$\frac {x21}{6} \leqslant 40$$
$$\frac {x12}{14} \leqslant 40$$
$$\frac {x22}{5} \leqslant 40$$

*Note : I know that this is not optimal either, it looks bad.*

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of decision variables
$$x_{ij} = \text{units of resource $i$ applied to disease $j$},\quad (i,j)\in\{1,2\}\times\{A,B\} $$
is a good start, but it is a lot easier to model this problem if we also add the decision variables
$$y_j = \text{number of people with disease $j$ cured},\quad j\in\{A,B\}. $$
Then the objective function is simply $\max 1000 y_A + 1200y_B$. The resource constraints are given by \begin{align}
x_{1A}+x_{1B}&\leqslant 630\\
x_{2A}+x_{2B}&\leqslant 300,
\end{align}
and the diseased population constraints by
\begin{align}
y_A&\leqslant 40\\
y_B&\leqslant 40.
\end{align}
Then the linking constraints
\begin{align}
-x_{1A}+9y_A&\leqslant0\\
-x_{2A}+6y_A&\leqslant0\\
-x_{1B}+14y_B&\leqslant0\\
-x_{2B}+5y_B&\leqslant0
\end{align}
ensure that we must apply the necessary amount of each resource to cure people from each disease. Now, under the germane assumption that we cannot cure a fraction of a person, we have the additional constraints that $y_A$ and $y_B$ are integer-valued. So we model this problem by a mixed-integer linear program:

\begin{alignat}{2}
\textrm{maximize }\;  & 1000 y_A + 1200y_B\\\\
\textrm{subject to }\; & x_{1A}+x_{1B}\leqslant 630&\\
& x_{2A}+x_{2B}\leqslant 300\\
& y_A\leqslant 40\\
& y_B\leqslant 40\\
& -x_{1A}+9y_A\leqslant0\\
& -x_{2A}+6y_A\leqslant0\\
& -x_{1B}+14y_B\leqslant0\\
& -x_{2B}+5y_B\leqslant0\\
& x_{ij}\geqslant0,\ & (i,j)\in\{1,2\}\times\{A,B\}\\
& y_j\in\mathbb Z_+,\ & j\in\{A,B\}.
& \end{alignat}

Comment: With MATLAB I found the optimal objective value to be 59600.